# Is there a Python-function that outputs the length of a row (or a column) of a 2D-array as an usable integer?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a Python-function(or algorithm) that outputs the length of a row (or a column) of a 2D-array as an usable integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

>>> x=np.array([[2,3,4], [23,32,4], [230, 230, 230], [3,2,3]])
>>> np.shape(x)
(4, 3)
>>> np.shape(x)[0]
4
>>> np.shape(x)[1]
3
```

Alternatively:

```py
>>> len(x)
4
>>> len(x[0])
3
```

Comment: I've actually read about the numpy-shape and length functions, but this was never explained. Thank you!